# How to add controller (not view) support to a server-side Blazor project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

While my server-side Blazor app is running, I want some Javascript code in `_Host.cshtml` to be able to post data to a controller action. Of course, this happens completely outside of the scope of, and is unrelated to, the Blazor app itself.

I thought this would be a matter of adding calls to `services.AddControllers()` and `endpoints.MapControllers()` at the appropriate places in `Startup.cs`. However, after doing this, and implementing the controller action, I made the following observations:

- Requests to the action are not routed and treated as "not found"
- In Razor, `@Url.Action` on the controller action returns a blank string

How can I add controller (not view) support to my server-side Blazor project in a way that overcomes the above two issues?

Comment: Please post what you tried

Answer (score 41):

Use: **endpoints.MapControllers()**

You can have this in your startup.cs:

```
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
        endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
    });
```

This controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class DownloadController : Controller
{
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment environment;
    public DownloadController(IWebHostEnvironment environment)
    {
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public IActionResult DownloadFile(string FileName)
    {
        string path = Path.Combine(
                            environment.WebRootPath,
                            "files",
                            FileName);

        var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);

        var result = new FileStreamResult(stream, "text/plain");
        result.FileDownloadName = FileName;
        return result;
    }
}
```

And this in your .razor page:

```
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<button @onclick="DownloadFile">Download</button>

@code {
     public void DownloadFile()
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"/api/Download/DownloadFile?FileName=BlazorHelpWebsite.zip", true);
    }
}
```

See:
https://github.com/ADefWebserver/Blazor-Blogs/tree/master/BlazorBlogs

Comment: That's what I've been doing, but I just noticed that, by using `MapControllers()`, entering urls corresponding to Blazor routes into the browser no longer works, and I can only navigate my site start from the homepage. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: OK, I've solved my problem. My conclusion is this: for some unknown reason, if I have "mixed routes" inside the same controller class (say the action methods have different root paths) then somehow `MapControllers()` will cause Blazor routes to stop working (and I have no idea why). I reorganize my controllers & actions and the problem is solved. Super weird.