# Unable to setup a controller on Blazor Server

Tags: c#, controller, blazor-server-side

I am trying to add an MVC, or WebAPI, or whatever controller to my Blazor Server project.

I have read numerous SO questions, blogs and etc. on the matter, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60022519/how-to-add-controller-not-view-support-to-a-server-side-blazor-project). None of them work.

No matter what I add to my "endpoints" or "app" in my "Configure" or "ConfigureServices" methods when I start my application in debug and try to make a request using Postman it times out.

I tried:

Adding controller exactly as shown in the linked answer.

Adding any and all of those in my Startup:

- endpoints.MapControllers()
- endpoints.MapGet("/aaa", async context => await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!"););
- endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute()
- app.UseMvc()
- app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute()

Neither does Postman get any answer (times out) nor does a breakpoint I've set in the "Get" method of the controller get triggered.

What can I do to get a controller working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did the following (which "worked on my machine"):

1. create a new BlazorApp:

```
dotnet new blazorserver -o BlazorApp --no-https
```

2. add a controller:

```
namespace BlazorApp.Controllers
{
  using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

  [ApiController]
  public class TestController : ControllerBase
  {
    [HttpGet("test")]
    public ActionResult<string> Test()
    {
      return "TODO";
    }
  }
}
```

3. add `endpoints.MapControllers();` to `Satrtup.cs`

```cs
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();            // new
    endpoints.MapBlazorHub();              // existing
    endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host"); // existing
});
```

4. run the app
5. go to http://localhost:5000/test (you'll get the `"TODO"` response)
6. go to http://localhost:5000 (you'll see the Blazor page)

#### EDIT

@Tessaract in the comments mentioned that the site was running on HTTPS while the plain HTTP was being queried (and therefor didn't work).

Comment: Well, ROCK ME, AMADEUS! It was the HTTPS. Like I wrote in the question I had already tried your approach and got zilch. So when I started a brand new project to verify something is iffy with my specific case and got the same "zilch" it clicked that it probably it's the HTTPS (both projects were created by default with HTTPS on, while I spied your "-no https" option and that got me thinking). It's always the tiny details. Anyway, since my browser hides the protocol part of the url I was always making calls to the HTTP version of the site. Your solution didn't help but... [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] If you put a note about checking querying the proper protocol "HTTP" or "HTTPS" you'll probably help some other nitwit along the line. :) I'll accept your answer, anyway.

Comment: @Tessaract good to hear you solved it. Added it to my answer.

Comment: Question: if user enter non existing api endpoint, for example: http://localhost:5000/test/something, how to show json 404 response instead of blazor 404 html response?

Comment: @SaleCar try adding an extra API endpoint like this: `[HttpGet("test/{*remaining}")]
  public ActionResult Other([FromRoute] string remaining)
  {
    return NotFound($"No such endpoint: /test/{remaining}");
  }`

Answer (score 0):

I know is too late, but meaby helpfull somenone in future.
Check add Controllers in Program.cs like this

```
builder.Services.AddControllers();
```

When builder is

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
```

And dont forget about this:

```
var app = builder.Build();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```