# How to realize Blazer Server External Login using razor components and API controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side

The document provides a scaffold way to use identity system but with razor pages. I've realized basic login/logout with razor components and API controller way. The form is built in razor components, and when submitting, it's posted to controller or just navigate to controller. Can anybody provide a sample of Microsoft external login using razor components and API controller?

Comment: Do you use `Blazor WebAssembly` instead of `Blazor Server`? In generally, blazor server does not have api as background. Can you provide the document whitch you refer to ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to implement a SAML or OAuth Login you just need controller endpoints to initiate the sign in and to handle the redirect from the identity provider.

If you are using Blazor Server you can map controllers using app.UseEndPoints method. See this answer. [How to add controller (not view) support to a server-side Blazor project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60022519/how-to-add-controller-not-view-support-to-a-server-side-blazor-project)

If you are using Blazor Wasm you would just map these endpoints in your service layer. If you use the ASP.NET Core hosted template the controller mapping should already be setup for you.

One you have controllers enabled you would need to setup the keys and redirect urls with the identify provider. Each identity provider usually has some of portal for setting this up. For example Azure AD would do this with an App Registration.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/auth-saml
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal

You would then use parameters from this registration to build the redirect to and from the provider, validate the token and either store it or generate an application specific cookie or token for your application to use.

If you are planning on using SAML either of these two libraries are very good at taking care of the internals of token validation.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sustainsys.Saml2.AspNetCore2
https://www.nuget.org/packages/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Mvc

This post for Itfoxtec's library has some good examples of the ASP.NET core configuration and endpoints required.

https://www.itfoxtec.com/IdentitySaml2